# How to disable Payment Method when "Pickup From Store" Delivery Method is selected in opencart?

Tags: opencart

In OpenCart V1551, How to disable Payment Method (Step 5 in Checkout Process) when "Pickup From Store" Delivery Method (Step 4 in Checkout Process) is selected?

Answer (score -1):

There is no possibility to disable the payment method selection step. Instead of this You would have to create (by copying of some basic payment method) one called *Pay on Pick Up* (or whatever, I guess there are some free for download on [OpenCart Extension page](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=pay%20on%20pickup)).

Then install and allow this payment method. Unfortunately OpenCart still does not allow to condition payment methods by previously picked shipping method (nor vice versa) thus this *Pay on Pick Up* payment method will always be available. Therefore the name of that payment method should fully describe that customer will pay for the goods when he comes to pick up them.

Anyway people still should be able to pay in advance (by credit card, by bank transfer, etc.) even they want to come to pick up what they have ordered (probably they do not want to pay for shipping and You are close enough to come by and pick the goods up).

Comment: IMO, Why would anyone will pay via Credit Card or Bank Transfer when they will Pickup the item from the store. Of course when they do pickup from store, they pay cash upon pickup. I think it's impractical to pay by other methods when picking up an item and not paying in cash. And for that reason, I thought of finding ways to modify that module. Thanks for the input anyway.